# Call function inside iFrame content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following in an html file (gallery.html) which creates a basic image gallery.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <!-- images are loaded into the container via the javascript function -->
</div>


 <script>
    function loadImages(images) {
        alert("Function Called");
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            $('#gallery').append("<img class='slides' src='"+images[i]+"'/>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

I then want to be able to put it in an iFrame and call the function to load the Images.

For example I have tried this without success

```
<iframe src="gallery.html" width='400px' height="200px" onload='loadImages(['pic1.png','pic2.png'])'></iframe>
```

and

```
<iframe src="gallery.html" width='400px' height="200px" onload='this.contentDocument.loadImages(['pic1.png','pic2.png'])'></iframe>
```

Is there a way that I can call the function in this way (a one liner) via the iFrame element in HTML? This would mean then that I could just put this one line of code in where ever I wanted the gallery (with different images) on a website.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it through [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow):

```
<iframe src="gallery.html" onLoad="this.contentWindow.loadImages(['pic1.png','pic2.png'])"></iframe>
```

Comment: Boom! Solved it, annoyed I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @jammycoder accept the anwer! edit: lol, i didnt realize that

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano he did it so quick I've gotta wait 4 minutes